# Is Google App Engine memcache secure?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

My application checks user authentication and authorization on every request and I am thinking of moving the authentication and authorization data from datastore to memcache.

Is memcache suitable for this usecase? Is it secure or I should not do it?

Comment: do you understand that memcache is a temporarily storage, all data can be lost at any moment?

Comment: Yes, I do. If memcache is lost, the system will write the data to memcache again. But is it secured?

Comment: ok, I thought you want to use memcache as a main storage

Comment: Use sessions instead. Sessions are unique per user, and they are automatically backed by memcache and datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Memcache is secure. If you save important content to Memcache you have to back it up on datastore because it can be evicted at any moment. There are datastore APIs on Python (NDB) and Java (Objectify) that manage the cache for you automatically, but I'm not sure about Go.

If your users log in with their Google Account you can use the Users API[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/).

---

Comment: better to use session as a comment says

Comment: Can you provide a link for that? The only reference to something similar to session I can find on the App Engine documentation is the Java Servlet API HttpSession.

Comment: explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, memcache is secure as the marked answer says (even shared memcache).

However as one comment says, you should really not reinvent appengine sessions, and instead use them. Google for "appengine go sessions" and you will find resources about it. The first link in that search:
https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/sadbox/appengine/sessions

shows you how to use them in Go.

Besides handling the memcache and datastore implementation, it has additional features like configurable expiration.

Comment: This is a Go question.

Comment: Ok, I see this is a valid alternative, but it should be noted this is not a feature of App Engine, but a 3rd party package.

Comment: indeed. thou it does the same as the official java and python inplementations in appengine. it does not use a new service, it uses existing datastore and memcache.

Comment: I don't see any official Session API for Python either. The Java one is an implementation of HttpSession interface from the Java Servlet API, I guess so already existing Java code that uses this interface continues working on App Engine. Also it is disabled by default for performance reasons.

Comment: its because its not an API. Google provides it in different ways. Python has sessions in webapp2